# Associar valores de um dropdown com uma coluna especifica no BD para query

Tags: java, sql

Tenho um filtro em meu site que encontra-se na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O real objetivo do mesmo é "buscar" destinos de viagem (Ex:. Paris, Barcelona, Bahia etc...) e apresentar na tela os mesmos.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de tabelas representadas pelos *bean's* abaixo (com comentários nas duas classes):

**Destination.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="destination")
public class Destination implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //Resto dos atributos omitidos para facilitar o etendimento

    //Cada atributo abaixo equivale a uma tabela, na qual possui os atributos no qual será baseado o filtro
    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_economic")
    private EconomicProfile economicProfiles;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_general")
    private GeneralProfile generalProfiles;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_social")
    private SocialProfile socialProfiles;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_trip")
    private TripProfile tripProfiles;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_weather")
    private WeatherProfile weatherprofile;
    //fim dos filtros

    //Getter and Setter
}
```

Abaixo segue o exemplo de uma tabela relacionada ao destino:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="economic_profile")
public class EconomicProfile implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_economic")
    private Long id;


    //Os atributos abaixo correspondem ao filtro de "Procuro por..." na imagem em anexo.
    @Column(name="economic_travel")
    private Boolean economic;

    @Column(name="intermediate_travel")
    private Boolean intermediate;

    @Column(name="luxury_travel")
    private Boolean luxury;

    //Getter and setter

}
```

Bem, optei em fazer desta forma, pois em cada filtro na hora de cadastrar o destino o usuário poderá escolher mais de um para cadastrar.

Ok, agora que chega a hora que me bateu a duvida. Como passar de forma correta os parâmetros para minha action? Ou seja como posso fazer o bind relacionando o valor selecionado em cada dropdown com a coluna correspondente no meu perfil?

Para ficar mais claro vou dar um exemplo abaixo:

```
<f:form id="form-filter-perfect-travel" modelAttribute="destination" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/perfect-travel-filter" method="get" class="form-filtro">

    <div class="box-select">
        <label>PROCURO POR</label>
        <f:select class="select01" path="economicProfiles">
            <option value="">Selecionar...</option>
            <option value="economic">Viagem Económica</option>
            <option value="intermediate">Viagem Intermediária</option>
            <option value="luxury">Viagem de Luxo</option>
        </f:select>
    </div>
</f:form>
```

Requisição GET:

**.../viatge/perfect-travel-filter?economicProfiles=intermediate**

Creio que tenha ficado mais claro agora. A questão é como pegar o valor selecionado para passar como parâmetro em uma *query* (*query* essa que retornara meus destinos), como a *query* abaixo de exemplo:

```
select 
    d.id_destination
    d.tenant_id,
    d.appear_website,
    d...
from
    destination d
        inner join
    economic_profile ON id_destination = id_economic
where
    (luxury_travel = ? || economic_travel = ? || intermediate_travel = ?);
```

Comment: Com JS tu consegue fácil, basta incluir o parâmetro na URL no `onChange` de cada selector, por exemplo, não?

Comment: Não seria o caso @BrunoCésar. Precisaria passar de certa forma o valor que foi selecionado no dropdown e atrelar ele no parâmetro correto dentro da query

Comment: Exatamente, tu tá usando taglib do spring, o path vai te gerar o `name` do select, que é o nome que tu usou como parâmetro. Neste teu exemplo, pega `name` (*economicProfiles*) e o valor da opção selecionada.

Comment: Entendi Bruno, mas a questão é essa. Cada valor da minha coluna em BD e um boolean e cada valor do meu select (option) é um texto. Como posso realizar esse "cruzamento"? Será que existe alguma outra forma mais simples?

Comment: João, você pode selecionar apenas um *economicProfile*? Por exemplo, isto também é válido: `economicProfiles=intermediate,luxury`? Eu não sei como estão os seus controllers, nem como está gerando as queries, mas existem muitas formas de tratar isto, algumas você precisará tratar no controller/service e passar o objeto com as opções para a camada de persistência.

Comment: Então Bruno eu posso selecionar somente um sim. O problema e como converter esses parâmetros passados via html para action serem convertidos para a coluna exata no banco para dai sim realizar um select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei achando uma solução (não muito elegante), mas acabou servindo exatamente para meu proposito.

Em minhas *tag's* de *select* *HTML* eu passei o nome de cada atributo igual ao *bean* na propriedade de *value*, assim como eu mostro abaixo:

```
       <select id="social-select"
            class="select01" name="social">
            <option value="">Selecionar...</option>
            <option value="accompanying">Acompanhante</option>
            <option value="alone">Sozinho</option>
            <option value="children">Crianças</option>
            <option value="friends">Amigos</option>
            <option value="elderly">Idosos</option>
            <option value="familyChildren">Sem Crianças</option>
            <option value="teenager">Jovem</option>
        </select>
```

Logo, o mesmo realiza uma chamada via *AJAX* (isso foi adotado, pois queremos exibir só um fragmento de pagina, sem "atualizar" ela inteira). O *controller* responsável por exibir o resultado realiza uma chamada para minha camada de serviço na qual faz um *Query* via *JPQL*

```
@Autowired
private CurrentTenantResolver<Long> tenantResolver;

@Autowired
private DestinationRepository destinationRepository;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Destination> filterDestinations(String economic, String general, String social, String weather, String trip){
    Long currentTenantId = tenantResolver.getCurrentTenantId();     
    String query = "SELECT d FROM Destination d INNER JOIN EconomicProfile e ON d.idDestination = e.id INNER JOIN GeneralProfile g ON d.idDestination = g.id INNER JOIN SocialProfile s ON d.idDestination = s.id INNER JOIN WeatherProfile w ON d.idDestination = w.id INNER JOIN TripProfile t ON d.idDestination = t.id WHERE (e."+economic+" = ?1 and g."+general+" = ?2 and s."+social+" = ?3 and w."+weather+" = ?4 and t."+trip+" = ?5)";        
    entityManager.setProperty(PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT, currentTenantId);
    return entityManager.createQuery(query).setParameter(1, true).setParameter(2, true).setParameter(3, true).setParameter(4, true).setParameter(5, true).getResultList();
}
```

Eu uso o *Spring Data*, mas atualmente eu adoto o modelo *SaaS* em minha aplicação, logo por motivos técnicos no qual eu teria que setar meu *tenant* corrente depois de ter começado a transação tive que optar em realizar a  consulta via *entityManager*. Ou seja cada *option* da minha *tag select* corresponde a coluna onde deve ser procurada pelo parâmetro "true" (1).

Dessa forma obtive sucesso.